# Bootstrap Tabs - How get rid of the 'active mouseout' style

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Tabs, I can't figure out the active state or find its selector, it seems like there are two active states. One when it's selected, and two when you mouseout of the selected tab.  I've searched StackOverflow but can't find or figure out what's going on here.

[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wt3labEqfnNGSSkXJmKM?p=preview), when you select one of the circles and then take your mouse off it, you see a white square behind the circle.

Here's the css:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active .services-icon-holder {
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active .services-icon-holder > .services-icon {
    color: #f0f;
} 

.nav-tabs {
        border-bottom: 0px solid #dddddd;
        font-size: 34px; 
        text-align: center;
        border: 0px solid #000000; 
        background-color: transparent; 
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 60px; 
}

.nav-tabs > li {
}



.nav-tabs > .active {
      border: 0px solid #000000;  
      background: transparent;
      color: #fff !important;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
        width:53px;
        height:53px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/HQoX5Eh.png");
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 53px 53px; 
        border: 0px solid #000000;     
        padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px; 
        margin-left: 54px;
        background-color: transparent; 
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
        width:53px;
        height:53px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5tXUkLT.png");
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 53px 53px; 
        border: 0px solid #000000;     
        padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px; 
        margin-left: 54px;
        background-color: transparent; 
         z-index: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active {
        z-index: 10px;

}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
        width:53px;
        height:53px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5tXUkLT.png");
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 53px 53px; 
        border: 0px solid #000000;
        background-color: transparent; 
        z-index: 10px;
}
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
        width:53px;
        height:53px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/5tXUkLT.png");
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 53px 53px; 
        border: 0px solid #000000;  
        background-color: transparent;
         z-index: 10px;
}
.tab-pane{
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.active { color: #ffffff!important; //for navbar, not tabs.
}

.active2 { 
  color: #000000!important; //for the tabs.
}
```

Here's the html:

```
      <tabset>

           <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">
          <span class="tabText">{{tab.content}}</span></br></br>
          <li class="tabText" ng-repeat="item in tab.list">
            <span class="tabText" ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>

        </tab>

      </tabset>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try overriding exactly what bootstrap assigns.

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, 
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus{
  background-color:transparent;
  border:0;
  /*Apply your actual overriding rules here and ignore the prev ones that was only for the demo*/
}
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QYPFb3?p=preview)**

basically in your specific case your rules gets overriden by the `:focus` rule that bootstrap assigns on the anchor via, `.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus`

Use browser console (eg:chrome) to inspect styles assigned to an element, you will get a good idea of which rule gets applied to an element.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, I was missing `.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus` - how did you find that? I could not find that inspecting with chrome -  I searched for hours.

Comment: @AgentZebra If you inspect chrome, on the RHS you will see the applied rules. Probably you missed that? Well you might have missed inspecting the anchor element perhaps

Comment: What's the RHS? :D I was inspecting the element with a right click, then clicking around on different elements.

Comment: Yup. I read them up and down for every element. I tell you, it was better than shakespeare :(  Thanks again tho, problem solved!

Comment: @AgentZebra see the snapshot i pasted, It will show you which rule precedes what. In this case it shows rule from bs(more specific) overrides the one you assigned in style.css

Comment: Ahh I see it now :D Thanks for the screenshot.  I think I may have ignored it cause it was grayed out - What does it mean when the selector name is gray? (in the Right Hand Column)

Comment: @AgentZebra It means that it is not applied in that scenario. here the hover stuff because i am no longer hovering it.

Comment: That's what I thought. Ah but it changes depending on what the user does. got it.